# Gradle > How to stop a Spring Boot application launched with gradle bootRun?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, gradle-plugin

I started a spring boot application using `gradle bootRun`.

Doing ctrl-c in the terminal where I launched the command does not stop the application.

What is then the correct way of stopping it?

Comment: Have you seen https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-shutdown ?

Comment: @ThiagoChagas it does not answer my question. I'll rephrase it. I want to know how to kill the spring boot application launched with the command gradle bootRun as doing ctrl-c on the commnad line does not seem to stop it.

Comment: You can check the process using netstat and then kill the process on that port.

Comment: Yes but I was expecting it to stop. So I'd like to know if it is normal or not for the process not to stop.

Comment: Hit `Ctrl` + `C` few more times? Try `Ctrl` + `D`? Are you using Gradle Daemon? Try to disable it (`--no-daemon`)?

Comment: @madhead I am using the gradle daeomn but why should I disable it?

Comment: It was just a guess

Answer (score 17):

You can use the command `gradle -stop` to stop the Spring Boot application.

Comment: I tried `./gradlew -stop` and it worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is killing the gradle demons, which is not right, there should be better way to stop spring boot servers gracefully without exceptions thrown.. do any know pl. share

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what operating system you are using but I am on a mac and was having the same problem, command + C wasn't working (on a mac the command key is equal to the Windows control key) but I used control+C and it did work. If you're on a Windows machine this doesn't help you but thought this might help others who are new to a mac.